# Safeguard a String from being null in JTextfield using if-else

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I'm a novice in Java. I want to remind my user if they didn't enter a `String` in the `JTextField`, so I use an `if`-`else` statement to safeguard. However, the reminder doesn't jump out when I test it.

How do I safeguard a string from being null in text field using if-else statement?

```
if ( !name == null && score >= 0) {
    Student stu = new Student(name, score);
    students.add(stu);
    }
}
else if(name == null) {
    reminder.setText("Could you tell me your name?");
}
else{
    reminder.setText("Enter numbers for score! Must be a positive number!");
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: the braces/formatting don't make sense. separately, checking if `name` is null would not catch an empty value – that is, `name` might contain an empty string `""`.

Comment: ```!name == null``` should be written ```name != null```

Comment: Please clarify: what is the context, framework you using, how you get the name, type of reminder etc. Also will be much nicer if you format the code properly.

Answer (score 2):

Null checks are `if (object != null)` and if you want to check if a text field is filled,

```
JTextField field = new JTextField();
String text = field.getText();
if (text != null && text.length() > 0) {
    System.out.println("Field has data");
}
```